# How can I Convert a .tex to a .pdf only using c++

Tags: c++, pdf, latex, tex

I am creating a **.tex** file with c++, that works fine, but I also want to **convert** this **.tex** file to a **pdf**.

The only lib I found that could help me was https://vog.github.io/texcaller/ but it seems to be working on Linux only bacause the necessary Headers like unistd.h, sys/wait.h and dirent.h dont exist on windows.

I think there is a way to do this with **pdflatex** but I dont understand how and I hope there is an easier way to do this or a better explanation.

Comment: If you can't find any libraries, you'll have to dig up the specification for Tex format and also for PDF format.  Have fun parsing the Tex file and reformatting for PDF.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Are you kidding?  TeX is Turing-complete (and a bit insane).  `texcaller` is called that because it **calls `tex`**, which is the only remotely accurate thing to do.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm not only talking about parsing the language.  I'm also talking about building a page or output.  I believe that the best method is to draw the page using TeX, then convert the page to PDF.  Maybe not go to the pixel level, but at least use some page elements.  Direct TeX to PDF may not be the most efficient or correct process here.